# How iterate on a Jdom Element that contains a list of node?

Tags: c#, java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am pretty new in XML parsing in Java using `org.jdom.**` and I don't know C#.

In this time I have to translate some method from C# to Java and I have the following problem.

In C# I have something like this:

```
System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodeList;
nodeList = _document.SelectNodes("//root/settings/process-filters/process");
if (nodeList == null || nodeList.Count == 0) {
    return risultato;
}

Objects.MyItem o;
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode n in nodeList){
    o = new Objects.MyItem(n.ChildNodes[1].InnerText, n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
    risultato.Add(o);
}
```

And I have translate it in Java in this way:

```
  public List<ProcessiDaEscludere> getProcessiDaEscludere() {
      Vector<ProcessiDaEscludere> risultato = new Vector<ProcessiDaEscludere>();

      Element nodeList;
      XPath xPath;

      try {
          // Query XPath che accede alla root del tag <process-filters>:
          xPath = XPath.newInstance("//root/settings/process-filters/process");
          nodeList = (Element) xPath.selectSingleNode(CONFIG_DOCUMENT);

          if (nodeList == null || nodeList.getChildren().size() == 0)
              return risultato;

          ProcessiDaEscludere processoDaEscludere = new ProcessiDaEscludere();


      }catch (JDOMException e){

      }

      return risultato;
  }
```

My problem is that now I have no idea about how iterate on the **Element nodeList** variable as do in C# by these lines:

```
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode n in nodeList){
    o = new Objects.MyItem(n.ChildNodes[1].InnerText, n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
    risultato.Add(o);
}
```

Someone can help me?